# Golang Check for existing items in slice of structs

Tags: go, struct, slice, goland

Let's say I've got the following structs:

```
type A struct {
    Field1 string
    Field2 string
}

type B struct {
    Field3 string
    Field4 int
}
```

and one more struct which uses the previous two:

```
type C struct {
    A
    MyList []B
}
```

Now, I've got some data that I want to group and map into a `C` struct and return a slice of `C`:

```
var results []C
```

I've got a slice of structs that looks like (since it's a slice if could happen that we have repeated A):

```
type X struct {
    A
    B
}
```

So I want to group the results by A. To do so I'm gonna iterate through a slice of X that my method receive as parameter:

```
var results []C

// Y is an slice of Xs 

for _, elem := range Y {
    // If elem.A exists then append elem.B into C.A
    // If not then add elem.A and elem.B into C
}
```

How can achieve the stuff stated in the comments above? I mean, how could I check if a struct `A` exists already in the slice of structs `C`?

Comment: so, what is the type of X ?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. Renamed to Y to avoid confusion. Basically Y is an slice of Xs

Comment: how would you do if those were not structs ? What else would you care about if nott comparability ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when you want to aggregate something by some value, you use a map. The key will be the value you want to aggregate by, type of `A` in your case.

This is easiest here too, this only requires the key type to be comparable.

You may simply gather the data like this:

```
// Example data:
xs := []X{
    {A{"a1", "a2"}, B{"b1", 2}},
    {A{"a1", "a2"}, B{"b11", 22}},
    {A{"a1", "a3"}, B{"b4", 5}},
}
m := map[A][]B{}

for _, x := range xs {
    m[x.A] = append(m[x.A], x.B)
}

fmt.Println(m)
```

This will output:

```
map[{a1 a2}:[{b1 2} {b11 22}] {a1 a3}:[{b4 5}]]
```

If you do need the result as `[]C`, iterate over the map and populate it:

```
for a, bs := range m {
    results = append(results, C{a, bs})
}
fmt.Println(results)
```

This will output:

```
[{{a1 a2} [{b1 2} {b11 22}]} {{a1 a3} [{b4 5}]}]
```

Try the examples on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5-TqBMqcFaP).

If by any chance `A` wouldn't be comparable, you would have to resort to using loops instead of map lookups where you would have to manually check for equivalence, and if you find a match, you'd perform the append operation.

Comment: Thanks icza. I had initially tried something similar but it was giving me an error. After looking at your example I know where the issue was: I was declaring `var m map[A][]B` and error it was throwing reads: assignment to entry in nil map. I changed the declaration to the one you have suggested and it's working although I'm still not clear on why it didn't work with the declaration without the initialization. Thanks

Comment: If you use `var m map[A][]B`, then the `m` map will remain its zero value (which is `nil` for maps). You can't put entries into a `nil` map. The short variable declaration I used: `m := map[A][]B{}`, it uses a composite literal to create a non-`nil` map value, which is assigned to `m`. This is an initialized map in which you may put entries. You could also write it like: `var m = map[A][]B{}`, or do the assignment after a variable declaration: `var m map[A][]B; m = map[A][]B{}`. Or use `make()` like this: `m = make(map[A][]B)`